# Centralized IIS to redirect to other IIS servers

Tags: windows, iis, web-server, rewrite, url

Basically what i'm after is to have a centralized IIS Server on the Local LAN where port 80/443 would be forwarded to from the router. Then through this server it can forward/redirect the requests to other servers in order to access the exchange OWA and for example the Remote Desktop web apps which are located on other local servers, the Exchange server and RDS Server respectively? For example I would access www.example.com and redirect me directly to this IIS centralized Server and www.example.com/OWA will redirect me to the Exchange server and www.example.com/RDWEB will redirect me to the RDS server. I need to know if such setup can be done so that I can have one main domain (example.com) and also one public IP Address corresponding

Answer (score 3):

By the sounds of it you want IIS to do the request on behalf of the user and deliver the content as such since externally the user could not otherwise access these resources (due to NAT).

The best way to achieve this I think would be to setup a reverse proxy. There's a blog post on the subject that the developer for an IIS extension has made which explains how to do this: http://blogs.iis.net/wonyoo/archive/2008/07/09/application-request-routing-arr-as-a-reverse-proxy.aspx This extension is available in Web Platform Installer.

I've never done this before, personally, but I'm a bit interested now and have a lab with multiple IIS servers rearing to go and will give it a shot just now.

**Addendum**
I've just finished making a rule and it seems to work with IIS 8.0 with no problems. I was able to rewrite to an internal network using specific patterns and I can provide an accompanying screenshot. So keep in mind that the GUI is slightly different and to access the bit that the guy in the blog was going on about you need to go to (from within your site) URL Rewrite -> Add Rule(s)... -> Blank Rule.

What you'll insert should look a bit like this depending your needs:
[image: IIS with rewrite rules]

Comment: : Ok so how can I specify then, if for example http://test.com/rds will take me to http://rds-srv/rds and if http://test.com/owa will take me to http://exch-srv/owa ? and I can't manage to get https internal sites.. do you have any idea why ? when I try to access the remote desktop website which is https by default through the re write I get this error message "Error 502 - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server"